# Connect Socket Android and join group

Tags: java, android, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to connect a Android's app with a server socket but when I don't know how I can subscribe a group. I'm using a WebSocketClient (import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;) and I receive a message as its is connected.

The next step is subscribe into a group to receive one or another information but I can't do this. I hope that you can help me.

Thanks!

```
URI uri;
    try {
        uri = new URI(url);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowParking.this, "OPEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String s) {
            final String message = s;

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(ShowParking.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(ShowParking.this, mWebSocketClient.getReadyState().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowParking.this, "CLOSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {

        }
    };
    mWebSocketClient.connect();
    Toast.makeText(ShowParking.this, "CONECTO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: *Why* can't you do it?

Comment: When I connect with the socket I received a message I connected but I do not know how I have to do to join into a group. To join into a group I have [5, "P1G219] but I don't know how to use it. What I have to do? Thanks.